# What's the name of this tool and what is it for?

Tags: tools

Found this in a box of tools and I have no idea what is called and its purpose, would someone let me know please.

There is a mark on it - T12399

[image]

Comment: Looks like a press or adjuster of some sort. It may have been part of a larger machine and wouldn't have a common name.

Comment: well, i can't figure if have been a part of something bigger as there is no any screw holes or anything on it to be fixed, it looks like a part designed that way

Comment: It does look like a tool used to press one part into another, such as a bearing race into its collar/cylinder, though I'm sure it has many other uses.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. It looks like you've created a second account. Please Google "merge Stack Exchange accounts" and ask a moderator to merge yours, and then use one going forwards. Thanks.

Comment: @DanielGriscom Moderators can't merge user accounts. If you see people with duplicate accounts, please direct them to the "contact" link at the bottom of the page to open a support ticket with SE; one of the options in the first entry field is "I need to merge user profiles".

Answer (score 3):

That is a fixture for repetitively cutting lengths of pipe or rod. The fixture is clamped to a workbench and the pipe is laid into the groove. The V-screw is then tightened to hold the rod. The end is then sawed off. The V-screw is loosened, the pipe/rod is advanced, then the process is repeated.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it's made to hold a rod or pipe. Maybe for drilling or cutting. Maybe it attaches to a drill press or saw.